# Not able to connect to corda nodes if devmode is false

Tags: corda

I followed the guide from here https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html from issuance of nodes certificates where i would create keys & certificates and sign root -> intermediate -> node -> SSL, and chaining the certificate among them to get the three (.jks) files.

When the network is in dev mode, I am able to bring a node up without errors but due to the certificate it will not start up as the network map does not recognise the node I assume.

With that in mind, I am trying to change the network map and the whole network to a non-devmode environment, when I start the networkmap up I seem to face `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors` in the logs, however on the interface I could see the network map is started up.

When I use the same root & intermediate keys to register another node into the network I am facing with the error:  `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQSecurityException: AMQ119031: Unable to validate user`

PS: I also tried to:

- Replicate the way dev mode created network map certificates instead of
  where the network map assigns a certificate (another level) as a
  corda.simple.notary
- Replicate network map certificate in this structure: 
  https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/docs/source/permissioning.rst 
  where root signs them and bypasses the intermediate CA

Any tips on how to bring up the network in a non-dev environment?

*Edit: i am using keytool to do the functions*
*stacktrace networkmap*:

> WARN ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,358Z [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@4d22265c)] core.client.createTransportConnection - AMQ212007: connector.create or connectorFactory.createConnector should never throw an exception, implementation is badly behaved, but we will deal with it anyway.
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:153) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at net.corda.node.utilities.X509Utilities.validateCertificateChain(X509Utilities.kt:153) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.messaging.VerifyingNettyConnector.createConnection(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:506) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.openTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1036) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1076) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.establishNewConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1254) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:891) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:795) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:238) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:772) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.createSessionFactory(BridgeImpl.java:803) [artemis-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.connect(BridgeImpl.java:860) [artemis-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl$ConnectRunnable.run(BridgeImpl.java:1045) [artemis-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:101) [artemis-commons-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
>   [WARN ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,408Z [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@4d22265c)] core.client.createTransportConnection - AMQ212007: connector.create or connectorFactory.createConnector should never throw an exception, implementation is badly behaved, but we will deal with it anyway.
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:153) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at net.corda.node.utilities.X509Utilities.validateCertificateChain(X509Utilities.kt:153) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.messaging.VerifyingNettyConnector.createConnection(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:506) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.openTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1036) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1076) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.establishNewConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1254) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:891) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:795) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:238) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:772) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.createSessionFactory(BridgeImpl.java:803) [artemis-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.connect(BridgeImpl.java:860) [artemis-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl$ConnectRunnable.run(BridgeImpl.java:1045) [artemis-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:101) [artemis-commons-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,470Z [main] internal.Node.registerWithNetworkMapIfConfigured - Node successfully loaded network map data from the database.
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,471Z [main] messaging.NodeMessagingClient.invoke - Network map is complete, so removing filter from P2P consumer.
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,490Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - Providing network services              : corda.notary.simple
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,490Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - Loaded CorDapps                         : corda-finance-2.0.0, mokochu-p2p-0.1, corda-core-2.0.0
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,492Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - Node for "NetworkMap" started up and registered in 8.09 sec
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,495Z [main] messaging.RPCServer.start - Starting RPC server with configuration RPCServerConfiguration(rpcThreadPoolSize=4, consumerPoolSize=2, producerPoolBound=4, reapInterval=PT1S)
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,833Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Loaded plugin Plugin[type=CRaSHShellFactory,interface=ShellFactory]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,834Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Loaded plugin Plugin[type=GroovyLanguageProxy,interface=Language]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,835Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Loaded plugin Plugin[type=JavaLanguage,interface=Language]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,835Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Loaded plugin Plugin[type=ScriptLanguage,interface=Language]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,836Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Loaded plugin Plugin[type=JaasAuthenticationPlugin,interface=AuthenticationPlugin]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,836Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Loaded plugin Plugin[type=SimpleAuthenticationPlugin,interface=AuthenticationPlugin]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,845Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Initialized plugin Plugin[type=GroovyLanguageProxy,interface=Language]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,845Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Initialized plugin Plugin[type=ScriptLanguage,interface=Language]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,848Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Initialized plugin Plugin[type=CRaSHShellFactory,interface=ShellFactory]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,848Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Initialized plugin Plugin[type=JaasAuthenticationPlugin,interface=AuthenticationPlugin]
>   [INFO ] 2018-03-12T09:55:54,849Z [Node thread] plugin.PluginManager.getPlugins - Initialized plugin Plugin[type=SimpleAuthenticationPlugin,interface=AuthenticationPlugin]
>   [WARN ] 2018-03-12T09:56:01,942Z [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@4d22265c)] core.client.createTransportConnection - AMQ212007: connector.create or connectorFactory.createConnector should never throw an exception, implementation is badly behaved, but we will deal with it anyway.
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:153) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>       at net.corda.node.utilities.X509Utilities.validateCertificateChain(X509Utilities.kt:153) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
>       at net.corda.node.services.messaging.VerifyingNettyConnector.createConnection(ArtemisMessagingServer.kt:506) ~[corda-node-2.0.0.jar:?]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.openTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1036) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1076) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.establishNewConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1254) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:891) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:795) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:238) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:772) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.createSessionFactory(BridgeImpl.java:803) [artemis-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl.connect(BridgeImpl.java:860) [artemis-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.cluster.impl.BridgeImpl$ConnectRunnable.run(BridgeImpl.java:1045) [artemis-server-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:101) [artemis-commons-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_144]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_144]

Comment: Two questions. 1. Which version of Corda is this?; 2. Are you sure you deleted the existing dev keystores before switching to `devMode=true`?

Comment: V2, yes i deleted the certs in the certificates folder

Comment: Can you post a full stacktrace for the errors?

Comment: you need setup your own certificates after devMode=true

Answer (score 1):

The error message is from `ArtemisMessagingServer`, which uses the node's TLS certificate. The message indicates that either the TLS certificate chain is set up incorrectly, or the root certificate in the node's truststore is wrong. Unfortunately, this is a `java.security` error, not a Corda error, and it doesn't provide information on the exact cause of the issue.

Your TLS certificate should have the following chain:

TLS certificate -> node CA certificate -> intermediate CA certificate -> root CA certificate

All of these certificates' keys should use a TLS-compatible algorithm (not EdDSA).